# Deprecation of multicore (mclapply) in R 3.0

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multicore, mclapply

I understand `multicore` is deprecated as of R version 2.14 and I was advised to start using the package `parallel` which comes built into the base of R 3.0.

Going through the documentation of `parallel`, I found that there are mainly two functions to call `parallel` and `collect` for example:

```
p <- parallel(1:10)
q <- parallel(1:20)
collect(list(p, q)) # wait for jobs to finish and collect all results
```

Since I'm not very familiar with the details of parallel computing, I've always used `multicore's` `mclapply` out of the box in my code. I wondering how I could take advantage of the new `parallel` package similarly to `mclapply`.

Cheers

Comment: `parallel` has its own `mclapply()` function that, as far as I know, should be a drop-in replacement for `multicore::mclapply()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned by @Ben Bolker, the `mclapply` is now integrated into R's base as of 3.0. Just load the package `parallel`. No need to have `multicore`

```
require(parallel) 
mclapply(1:30, rnorm)
```